# How to print lambda function arguments when lambda is called in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I have defined a lambda expression and I want as I use it later in my code to print the changing each time parameters within the lambda call.  What should the print(lambda) look like?

```
x = lambda a,b,c: a+2*b+3*c

print(x(1,2,3))   
print(x(1,1,1))   
print(x(1,4,1))
```

```
Desired sample output
```

14 for a=1, b=2, c=3

6  for a=1, b=1, c=1

12 for a=1, b=4, c=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this lambda function will give you your desire output

```
>>> x = lambda a,b,c: str(a+2*b+3*c)+" for a="+str(a)+" ,b="+str(b)+" ,c="+str(c)
>>> print(x(1,2,3))
14 for a=1 ,b=2 ,c=3
```

Comment: A minor correction regarding spaces and commas:
`x = lambda a,b,c: str(a+2*b+3*c)+" for a="+str(a)+", b="+str(b)+", c="+str(c)`
Your answer was the one I was looking for.